# How to change href of a button without ID

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the `href` on this element:

```
"<button onclick="smoothscroll()" class="btn btn-white btn-small" href="#contacto">blah blah <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>"
```

It doesn't have an ID so I tried like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-white btn-small')[0].href="https://www.mysite.cl/#"
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. any ideas? I have other element that works just like I want this button to work:

```
"<button onclick="smoothscroll()" class="btn" href="#">blah blah</button>"
```

But I also tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-white btn-small')[0].href="#"
```

And it doesn't work either

Comment: `'document.querySelector(button[onclick=smoothscroll()]).href="blah"`

Comment: can you also add the HTML file?

Comment: hello! thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work either, maybe i should mention that there are 6 "smoothscroll()" buttons just like this one

Comment: Why are there quotes around your `<button>` tag?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add an ID? Just curious what the scenario is that makes it so you cant add an ID on there.

Comment: Hello kmoser and Mr. Moriarty,
The quotes I added because I'm new here and it took me a while to understand how to insert code in the post, my bad. They are not part of the code.

The reason I can't add an ID is that I don't really have access to edit the HTML code manually (I can only inset new code), this is an emergency from a client with no development team, so I'm trying to help by inserting a line of code through Google Tag manager in order to replace de href

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what the `href` is then select it using that.

Since `href` is not standard to a [`button` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), to update the `href` attribute, use `setAttribute`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button[href="#contacto"]')
button.setAttribute('href', "#");
console.log(button)
```

```html
<button onclick="smoothscroll()" class="btn btn-white btn-small" href="#contacto">blah blah <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

If you have control of the html, then you should look to change the `button` to an [`a` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) instead.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I don't have access to the HTML yet, I'm trying to fix an emergency through custom HTML on Tag Manager. This been said, I think I only have the chance to use functions to replace code. I tryied what you said, but I get an error:

#This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration.

Comment: Try `var button = document.querySelector('button[href="#contacto"]')`

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use `href` as attribute for `html button`, use this instead..

```
<a href = '#blablabla'>Scroll to bla bla bla </a>
```

Then add this css property to the page

```
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

The above `css` will automatically cause smooth scrolling each time a user  scrolls by clicking a link.

**But if you insist**

Try this.. Change your buttons to

```
"<button onclick="smoothscroll(this)" class="btn btn-white btn-small" href="#contacto">blah blah <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>"
```

Then your `smoothscroll()` function should look like..

```
function smoothscroll(button){
 button.setAttribute('href', 'Your new link');
}
```

Comment: It's not even just "not advised" to use `href` on a `<button>`, it's actually [not a valid Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), and since `href` isn't a [Global Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), it will have no effect with having an explicit handler attached to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have mentioned that I don't have acces to the HTML code of the page, I can only edit by html functions since im changing it through Google Tag Manager. I also know this isn't adviced either, but I can't do anything about it yet, it's an emergency and client's developers are not able to edit because of a huge company emergency they are on right now

Comment: Hello, I also tryied the "Insist" solution, the good news is that I finally did get some response on the buttons, bad news are that I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
    at smoothscroll (<anonymous>:3:28)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (?gtm_debug=x:243)

Comment: I understand why, is because I can't really change the button. because of what i said about not having direct acces to the html